# How to to split jQuery UI accordion in 2 columns

Tags: jquery, user-interface, accordion

I would like to split jQuery UI accordion in 2 columns but I cannot figure out how to do that.
When I put

```
div style="float:left; width:50%;"
```

accordion doesn’t work properly any more. 
I have been customized this demo http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/collapsible.html

Can somebody help me please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Collapse content</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="ui/jquery.ui.accordion.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            animated: false,
            active: false,
            autoHeight: false
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="demo">
    <div id="accordion">

    <div style="float:left; width:50%;">
        <li><a href="#">TITLE 1</a>
        <p>TEXT 1</p></li>

        <li><a href="#">TITLE 2</a>
        <p>TEXT 2</p></li>
    </div>

    <div style="float:left; width:50%;">
        <li><a href="#">TITLE 3</a>
        <p>TEXT 3</p></li>

        <li><a href="#">TITLE 4</a>
        <p>TEXT 4</p></li>
    </div>

    </div><!-- End accordion -->
</div><!-- End demo -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been successful splitting the accordion into two sections, albeit in a bit of a roundabout way. There might be a better way of going about this, but I am not currently aware of one.

```
<div id="accordion">    
    <h3><a href="#">Top Accordion Content Area</a></h3>
        <div id="TopA">
            <div id="Top_A_left">      
                <p><b>Content for left section goes here</b></p>
            </div>  

            <div id="Top_A_right">
                <p><b>Content for right section goes here</b></p>
            </div>

        </div>
 ...[rest of the accordion code goes here]...
```

And of course you can tweak your CSS to give you the layout you want. I'd recommend attaching an ID to the DIV in which both sections are contained, and then configuring some style settings in the CSS as well, otherwise you might end up with either too much or not enough padding.

the CSS:

```
#Top_A_Left 
{
   width:20%;
   float:left;
}

#Top_A_Right
{
   width:auto;
   float:left;
}
```